# Contradiction abide or contradiction abides

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

[While the contradiction between modernity and deeply retrograde systems of discrimination **abide**, the acknowledgment by the world’s leading space agency of those that helped it become so is a welcome correction.](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/editorials/nasa-afro-american-apollo-11-black-americans-one-small-step-2-5781471/)

I think **contradiction** is the subject and therefore **abides** should be used. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.  As written, it is not grammatical.  Also, it's a horrible sentence.

If it's any consolation, much of the article is poorly written.  To the author's credit, the advanced vocabulary is correct, and there are no other glaring grammatical errors, but the overall syntax is unnecessarily convoluted.  For example

> NASA has now renamed the street outside its Washington headquarters Hidden Figures, to honour those that were once treated as second-class citizens even as they literally shot for the moon, and managed to hit the target.

The last part is the kind of "added detail" that is better inserted as a non-restrictive clause, rather than as a weird afterthought:

> ... to honour those that were once treated as second-class citizens even as they literally shot for -- **and managed to hit** -- the moon.

Even so, a good editor would likely have marked out "managed to hit" as pointless bloviating.  It's fine just to say:

> ... to honour those that were once treated as second-class citizens even as they literally shot for the moon.

I could go on and pick apart each of the paragraphs in this article, but this is the kind of writing typical for this publication, I would suggest not to rely on it as a reference.